# Flutter App: The method 'call' was called on null

Tags: flutter

I have make an application which search for something and displys them on the list. Once the search has some data, it fails with following error.

> ```
> The method 'call' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: call()
> ```

it is failing at

```
child: SearchBar
```

Following is my body.dart file.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SearchBar<BookList>(
              onSearch: _isOnline
                  ? search
                  : _showToast(constants.offlineErrorMessage),
              onItemFound: _showToast("Data Found"),
              loader: const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
              emptyWidget: Center(
                  child: SelectableText.rich(
                _isOnline
                    ? TextSpan(
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                              text:
                                  "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tNo Data found!"),
                        ],
                      )
                    : TextSpan(text: constants.offlineErrorMessage),
              )),
             ),
              textStyle:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Search function:

```
Future<List<BookList>> search(String search) async {
  if (!isLoadingFirstTime) _showToast("Tap on image to maximize");
 
      List<BookList> finalList = await fetchDownloadableLink(bookList);
      isLoadingFirstTime = true;
      
       return finalList;
    }
  } catch (Exception) {
    throw Exception;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide search function also

Comment: Updated the question with search function

Answer (score 0):

hope u create function called **search**

try to create another method like this.

```
Function SearchFunction(){
  return search();
}
```

and place this method there

```
onSearch: _isOnline
              ? SearchFunction
              : _showToast(constants.offlineErrorMessage),
```

Comment: `Future<List<Object>> search(String search) async {`

A function is created with Future return type. It is failing while rendering all the data coming from this function. 

RenderObjectElement.insertChildRenderObject() is deprecated.

insertChildRenderObject() has been deprecated in favor of insertRenderObjectChild(). See
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63269 for details.